# Unexpected result for body.getOoxml

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I want to get the comments in the word online by word.js, I tried with `body.getOoxml`, but it return unexpected result when I add a comment on the last words of the document.

### Expected Behavior

Ruturn all the comments when I use with `body.getOoxml`.

### Current Behavior

`body.getOoxml` did not return the comment which is added on the last words in the doc.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Get ooxml by

```
function xmlToCommentsProcess() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        console.log(6000);
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;
            // Queue a commmand to get the OOXML contents of the body.
            var bodyOOXML = body.getOoxml();
            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands
            // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    var request = {
                        ooXml: bodyOOXML.value,
                        filePath: Office.context.document.url,
                        fileName: basename(Office.context.document.url)
                    };
                    xmlToComments(request);
                });
        });
    });
}
```

2. eg, I have a doc like

[image]
 3. If there is no additional lines under `4567989`, the output for `bodyOOXML.value` will miss comments `645456`

4. If I add additional lines under `4567989`, the output for `OXML.value` will contains comment `645456`

### Environment

- Platform [Office Online]
- Host [Word]
- Browser : Chrome

Comment: I can reproduce. If there is no content at all after the last comment, then the last comment is not included in the returned OOXML. Happens on Word Online, but not Word desktop. (Both Chrome and Firefox.) If you haven't done so already, please raise this issue on the repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js. Be sure to report any answer you get there back here. Thanks.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thanks for confirming, and I have submit an [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/384), if I got any response, I will report back.